# Understanding rails s conflict with Puma and Capybara. How do I properly install puma in the Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am inheriting a code base where the tests have been abandoned for a little over a year. I am trying to clean up the test suite as much as possible but I am having a difficult time teasing out my integration tests with 1. Capybara 2. Puma, 3. Selenium, 4. Starting the Rails Server with rails s.

Here is my initial setup and problem with the Rails 4.2 app. So without doing anything from the get go, when I execute rails testing, I get the following error:

> Capybara is unable to load `puma` for its server, please add `puma` to your project or specify a different server via something like `Capybara.server = :webrick`. (LoadError).

I want to point out that in a separate file named `start-dev`, I have the following in its contents:

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

When I execute this comand with ./start-dev, I am able to view my development app with this url defined in my `/etc/hosts` `127.0.0.1      secure.ssl.local`

Now here is where I start to run into trouble, Through reading some github forums regarding capybara and puma, I start by adding puma into my Gemfile and bundle install but now I am unable to see my development app through the browser at `secure.ssl.local`.

This is the erorr I get:

> /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:67:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): "tcp://0.0.0.0\r:3000" (URI::InvalidURIError)

I noticed that in the start up though, when I execute `./start-dev` which if you remeber has `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`, I see this:

```
Booting Puma rails 4.2.11.1 application starting in development on https://0.0.0.0:3000
```

So I am confused by this error. Is Puma blocking my port of `3000` meaning that I have to change the port of Puma? And what makes this even more confusing is that instead of running `./start-dev` in the terminal and I simply run `rails s -b 0.0.0.0` it magically works except it only works if I navigate to `localhost:3000` and not `secure.ssl.localhost`. This is important because on secure.ssl.localhost I have and need a certificate and localhost I don't.

And finally to add one more layer of confusion, when I run the tests with the puma gem installed and run `rake test` I get this with Puma:

> Capybara starting Puma...
>   * Version 4.2.1 , codename: Distant Airhorns
>   * Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
>   * Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:36608

And the test takes ages to load. There is a lot going on but I guess my question can be summarised by the following?  When I install puma into my rails application, do I need to specify it on a specific port so it does not conflict with my app? Without puma, my tests can't run and my `./start-dev` file works. With puma, my tests are kind of working but my `./start-dev` file isn't anymore. Surely there must be a standard to configure puma. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Install puma only for test environment by putting it into test group:

```rb
group :test do
  gem "puma"
end
```

Or do as Capybara proposes and put `Capybara.server = :webrick` into your `spec/rails_helper.rb`

FYI: Rails uses puma as default web server if puma is installed